# Sending spam mail from my postfix SMTP server

Tags: email, postfix-mta, spam-prevention, smtp-auth

Long time user and first time poster on stack-overflow but I'm a bit stumped.

A few months ago I bought and set up a virtual machine running CentOS 6 so that I could host a few websites and a mail server for myself and a few clients. I set the entire thing up myself from the Unix knowledge I already had, including the mail server - which was at the time something I had never done before.

The mail server is working as intended, dovecot enforces IMAP logins and everything was running smoothly, until recently when I noticed one of the domains has been sending mail from un-registered users.

To give you an extract from the log at /var/log/maillog

```
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: 45A9520F2DF8A: from=<daisy_gibson@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1321, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: A98FC20F2D350: from=<regina_reeves@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1420, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: E45E820F2DD3A: from=<robyn_holland@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1334, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: AD06220F28246: from=<lorraine_murphy@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1393, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: DC00D1849D7CC: from=<kristine_gardner@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1401, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
s18646572 postfix/qmgr[3763]: 890EE20F28F2A: from=<mae_shaw@friendsdomain.uk>, size=1418, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

So from what I can gather somebody is using his domain "friendsdomain.uk" but also piggybacking on our SMTP server to send the mail, given that it's being deposited into our queue.

I found a tool online to help [test SMTP relay](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server) and managed to configure some rules to prevent SMTP relays - at least through this tools. Users now need to be SASL authenticated in order to send mail.

However, the mail is still going out - postfix doesn't seem to be stopping the spam at all which leads me to believe that whoever is using the server is already authenticated. I've changed the passwords of all users but that doesn't seem to have halted the problem - and the logs don't indicate which user is being used to send the mail.

Extract of my postfix config below:

```
### SMTP Setup ###
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_login_maps
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unlisted_sender
```

I added the SMTP_sender restrictions following some other answers I found on the site - which seemingly prevented the relaying at least.

I paused the SMTP server and inspected a few of the mail items in the queue, extract below.

```
Subject: 1 New SnapF#ck AlertN=X-PHP-Originating-Script: 48:plugin.php(1959) : eval()'d codeN$
Date: Wed, 9 Dec 2015 22:02:26 +0000N5From: Kelly Fleming <kelly_fleming@friendsdomain.uk>N@Message-ID: <64b6713d232e7a4f88e85344aac5cc9c@friendsdomain.uk>N
X-Priority: 3w
0NCX-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)N
```

The headers indicate that whoever is doing this is using a [PHP mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)

SO the problem still remains, people are sending spam using my SMTP server - I need a way to either user logins for the User logins, unless an account has been compromised in which case I need a way to find out which. I can't simply suspend the accounts as the genuine users still need access to their email - however now we're receiving so many hits that the TCP sockets are preventing other services from running.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the mystery (somewhat)

The mail was coming internally from one of our hosted sites. Either the site has been configured to use the SMTP with authentication or was not required to authenticate because it was on localhost.

The clue was in the sending error logs

`Dec 10 11:35:15 s18646572 postfix/pickup[6439]: 9A7BA20F29112: uid=48 from=<sally_weaver@friendomain.uk>`

The user id of the sender UID=48 indicated that it was a local user, and after checking the passwd file this was confirmed to be the apache user.

It is now evident that some part of the website hosted on frienddomain.uk is being exploited to send spam, and after suspending the website and restarting services the mail ceased.

The problem now is finding and removing the exploit, however if you wish you can disable the mail() function in your php.ini file.

Comment: I know this is somewhat late, but I had the same problem with a hosted site enabling spamming. I installed `maldet` (http://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/), scanned my /var/www folder and found the culprit.